# Generar choices en selectInput() basado en selección anterior

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

estoy realizando una aplicación en Shiny, en la pagina principal tengo 3 inputs, pero hay un cuarto input que debe completarse dependiendo del valor que tome el input nro 2. Los primeros 3 inputs están sobre un sidebarLayout/sidebarPanel y el cuarto input sobre un mainPanel/TabsetPanel.

```
sidebarLayout(
        #inicio sidebarpanel
        sidebarPanel(id="sidebar","Selecciona las opciones",width=4,
                 
                 selectInput("Pais",
                             label="Paises",
                             choices=c(NOMBPAISES)
                             
                 ),
                 selectInput("Canal",
                             label="Canales",
                             choices=NOMBRECANAL    
                 ),
                 selectInput("Categoria",
                             label="Categorias",
                             choices=NOMBRECATEGORIA  
                 )
    )
```

.......
Y el otro input

```
tabPanel("Data Gps", 
                                   
         fluidRow(
                  selectInput("SubGiros",
                          label="TipoSubGiros",
                          choices= NOMBRESUBGIROS 
                          )
                ),
```

Los subgiros dependen del canal que tome el input. Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Una de las maneras en las que puedes hacer esto es definiendo un `reactiveVal()` (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.0/reactiveVal.html) antes de comenzar a definir el UI de tu aplicación.

Haces que tu cuarto input dependa de este reactiveVal.

Posteriormente en el server defines la lógica que modificará este reactiveVal, afectando consecuentemente tu input.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta debería ser: "Generar choices en selectInput() basado en selección anterior" o algo similar.

Para esos casos, se recomienda usar un `uiOutput()`. En este caso es para generar tu cuarto `selectInput()`. Supongamos que tuvieras los subgiros correspondientes a los canales en una lista.

```r
lista <- list(canal1 = c("subgiro1", "subgiro2"),
              canal2 = c("subgiro3", "subgiro4"))
```

Tu segundo `selectInput()` podría tener en `choices` los nombres de elementos de la lista.

```r
selectInput("Canal",
            label="Canales",
            choices=names(lista)    
)
```

En lugar de poner  directamente tu cuarto `selectInput()` usarías `uiOutput()` para indicarle dónde quieres que se genere. En este caso sería en el `tabPanel()` que muestras en el ejemplo.

```r
tabPanel("Data Gps",
    fluidRow(
        uiOutput("cuartoInput")
    )
)
```

Para generar las `choices` del cuarto `selectInput()` necesitarías hacer subsetting de la lista según el nombre del elemento  que escojan en tu segundo `selectInput()`. Esto lo haces en el `server` dentro de `renderUI()`. Fíjate que usamos el `outputId` de tu segundo `selectInput()`.

```r
output$cuartoInput <- renderUI({
  selectInput("SubGiros",
              label = "TipoSubGiros",
              choices = lista[[input$Canal]])
})
```